# Express js. wanting to communicate between a production server and a local server

Tags: node.js, http, express

Let's say I have a production server @ http://foo.com and I have a local server @ localhost:3000.

Is there a way to communicate between a production server and a local server?

My main goal is to update the production server's database and write files into prod server's directory.

Comment: Maybe just use git

Answer (score 0):

you can connect to server like this :

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```